# How To Move a Paperclip Attachment Keeping Path Settings In Mind?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, paperclip

I have two models. One being Image which has an attachment called "file" and saves to "/photos". These would be simple images that would be inside of, say, an album. I also have users that have an attachment called "avatar" which saves to "avatars/etc etc". How can I copy one attachment (@image.file) over to my user to save it as his avatar? I want the user to be able to select an image that he/she has in their album images and use it as an avatar. I want to copy it though so if the user ever deletes that image from their album, it won't delete their avatar.

### User Model Snippet:

`has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {
      :huge => '220x220!',
      :full => '72x72!',
      :medium => '48x48!',
      :small => '24x24!'
    },
    :path => ':rails_root/public/avatars/:userid_prefix/:userid/:style-:random.:extension',
    :url => '/avatars/:userid_prefix/:userid/:style-:random.:extension',
    :default_url => :default_avatar_url`

### Image Model Snippet

`has_attached_file :file,
    :styles => {
      :large => '640x480',
      :avatar => '72x72!',
      :cover => '160x160!'},
    :path => ':rails_root/public/photos/:userid_prefix/:userid/:id_:style-:random.:extension',
    :url => '/photos/:userid_prefix/:userid/:id_:style-:random.:extension'`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the most efficient approach in the world, but you could have Paperclip import the image from the URL on your site.

Let's say you present the user with their photos, and whichever one they click calls `User#update` with `params => { :avatar_url => 'http://www.yourownwebsite.com/url/of/image.jpg' }`.

You then process this param in the controller doing something like:

```
if params.has_key? :avatar_url
  begin
    @user.avatar = open params[:avatar_url]
  rescue
    logger.warn "Unable to open #{params[:avatar_url]}"
  end
end

if @user.save
   # Regular response handling goes here...
```